# Negate regex matching a single word to return no matches

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to negate this regex:

```
^sofia$
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If it's the whole pattern, just negate the result of the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!sofia$).*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sQ5oD2/1)

EDIT: In case you are just interested in a boolean result with `preg_match`, you may remove `.*$`.

Also, if input strings contain newline symbols, a singleline modifier `/s` (or its inline variant `(?s)`) is required. E.g.

```
(?s)^(?!sofia$).*$
```

Or

```
/^(?!sofia$).*$/s
```

Your `^sofia$` matches a string/line equal to `sofia`, so you must be looking for a regex that will match any string/line that is not equal to `sofia`.

Negative lookaheads can be used to restrict generic patterns. Here, `.*` matches any characters but a newline, 0 or more times. The lookahead checks if there is no `sofia` right at the start of the string/line.

Comment: yup. that works. thanks! I was doing the negative lookahead incorrectly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you need `s` flag, since `.` reject new line by default. It's also possible to just remove `.*$`, since they are redundant when used with `preg_match`.